# What is the fastest way to empty a list in Python?

Tags: python

What is the fastest way to empty a list in Python?
Is `clear()` the fastest?

Also, what is the most memory efficient way of doing it?
I heard Reinitializing the list won't clear it, but let GarbageCleaner delete the actual contents based on the remaining references.

Which way would be the fastest, and if possible most memory efficient?

Comment: [Performance rant](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/), clearing a list will not be your bottleneck.

Comment: If this kind of mico-optimisation is important for your code, then python isn't the right language for you

Comment: However, the question is still a valid one- it's not too broad or unclear (and i didn't dv)

Comment: @Chris_Rands - I'd say it is too broad, you don't know what the list contains (are they objects. What does it mean by empty? What should happen if other references of the objects exist? And I downvoted because there is no research effort shown.

Comment: What is "GarbageCleaner"? The name of a feature? Or just [garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29)?

Answer (score 2):

`ls.clear()`, `del ls[:]`, and `ls[:]=[]` are all identical in their performance:

```
$ python3 -m timeit -n 1000 "ls=list(range(10000)); ls.clear()"
1000 loops, best of 5: 219 usec per loop

$ python3 -m timeit -n 1000 "ls=list(range(10000)); del ls[:]"
1000 loops, best of 5: 215 usec per loop

$ python3 -m timeit -n 1000 "ls=list(range(10000)); ls[:]=[]"
1000 loops, best of 5: 218 usec per loop
```

I agree with the others that if you need to even think about these kinds of micro-optimizations you're using the wrong language.

I would always just use `ls.clear()` since that's the most obvious, most readable, and cleanest way imo.

Comment: A small detail to add, all 3 of these methods remove a reference to said memory. `ls.clear()` is equivalent to `del ls[:]` per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists). When garbage collection decides to collect, it will see if there's any references pointing to said memory and if none are, it will reclaim the memory. If this memory is an object, `__del__()` will then be invoked.

Answer (score 1):

This is the fastest way to do it:

```
list *= 0
```

Comment: Why copy 2 of the already given answer? Without answering to the question (which is the fastest. The existing answer also give 3 answers, but argue that they are equivalent). You don't even need that hijacking of previous answer, since you bring a new one (`l *= 0`), which is, indeed, the fastest so far! (quite visibly at that: other are all in the vicinity of 13 to 15 μs — not 200 as in the existing answer, that times the list creation more than its destruction — yours, 9 μs!)